# Can I get django model object by pk which is string?

Tags: django

Is it okay if I get model object by string pk?

I'm using basic model's pk.

What I mean is like:

```
str_pk = str(21)
object = ExampleModel.objects.get(pk=str_pk)
```

Is it possible and working well?

Comment: Yes, django converts what it needs

Comment: I am pretty sure this will work. But better is to use `pk=int(str_pk)` That way if it fails because of an string that does not contain a numeric value then you will get a `ValueError` instead of something based on the database function that might not be as obvious.

Comment: "Yes, django converts what it needs "
No it doesn't. Django is written in Python, and Python errors when given incorrect dataypes. Strings and integers are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKs are integers, not strings. Don't cast to a string -- cast to an int if necessary:

```
str_pk = int(21)
```